# Spivak, Ch. 3 Functions, Problem 28c: what exactly is being asked be proven?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My issue with this item of this question is that it is not clear to me exactly what is being asked to be proven.

> Let $F$ be the set of all functions whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$. Show
> that $P10-P12$ cannot hold. In other words, show that there is no
> collection $P$ of functions in $F$ such that $P10-P12$ hold for $P$.
> (It will be sufficient, and will simplify things, to consider only
> functions which are zero except a two points $x_0$ and $x_1$).

Note in what follows that it is pretty confusing already that $P$ is used to denote the collection of functions in $F$, given that $P$ denotes the collection of all positive numbers, and possibly all functions that are always positive (see below).

$$$$

**$P10-P12$ are properties of real numbers defined in the first chapter. Here they are:**

> **$P10$ (Trichotomy Law)** For every number $a$, one and only one of the
> following holds:
>
> i) $a=0$
>
> ii) $a$ is in the collection $P$
>
> iii) $-a$
> is in the collection $P$
>
> where $P$ is the collection of all positive numbers.
>
> **$P11$ (Closure under addition)** If $a$ and $b$ are in $P$, then $a+b$
> is in $P$.
>
> **$P12$ (Closure under multiplication)** If $a$ and $b$ are in $P$, then
> $a\cdot b$ is in $P$.

$$$$

**This is how I translate these properties if they were written for functions**

> **$P10$ (Trichotomy Law)** For every function $f$, one and only one of the
> following holds:
>
> i) $f(x)=0\ \forall x$
>
> ii) $f$ is in the collection $P$
>
> iii) $-f$ is in the collection $P$
>
> where $P$ is the collection of all functions $f$ such that $f(x)>0\ \forall x$
>
> **$P11$ (Closure under addition)** If functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are in $P$, then $f_1+f_2$
> is in $P$.
>
> **$P12$ (Closure under multiplication)** If functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are in $P$, then
> $f_1 \cdot f_2$ is in $P$.

$$$$

The question as it is written seems to initially imply that we must show that $P10-P12$ cannot all hold for all functions in $F$. Then it says "in other words, show there is no collection $P$ of functions in $F$ such that $P10-P12$ hold for $P$".

I can find a subset of functions in $F$ that has all three properties:

Consider functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)>0\ \forall x$ and $g(x)>0\ \forall x$.
Regarding $P10$, neither function is the constant zero function, and both are in $P$, but $-f$ and $-g$ are not in $P$. So $P10$ holds for both functions.

$f(x)+g(x) > 0\ \forall x$ so $P11$ holds.

$f(x)\cdot g(x) >0\ \forall x$ so $P12$ holds

Is the collection of functions with the two elements $f$ and $g$ not a collection such that all three of $P10$, $P11$, and $P12$ hold? Yet of course this doesn't mean all functions with real domain have all three properties.

**Here is the solution in the solution manual**

> Let $f$ and $g$ be the two functions which are $0$ except at $x_0$ and
> $x_1$, with $f(x_0)=1$ and $g(x_0)=0$, $g(x_1)=1$. Neither is $0$, so
> $f$ or $-f$ would have to be in $P$, and likewise $g$ or $-g$. But
> $(\pm f)(\pm g)=0$, which contradicts $P12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection $P = \{ f, g \}$ of two functions satisfies none of the three properties:

P10 is not satisfied because in it, you need to consider *all* functions, not just those in $P$. Both of your functions are positive everywhere. So if I give you a function $h$ that is positive at one point and negative at another, neither $h$ nor $-h$ will be among the two functions in your set. It it also not the zero function. (This also shows that it won’t help to enlarge your set to include all functions that a positive everywhere.)

P11 is not satisfied, because you don’t need to show that the function $f + g$ defined by
$$
  (f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)
$$
is positive everywhere; you need to show that it is in your set $P$. But for any $x$, $f(x) + g(x)$ will be bigger than both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, so it can be neither of the functions $f$ or $g$.

P12 might be satisfied in very particular circumstances (namely if both $f$ and $g$ are $1$ everywhere); in all other cases, you run into similar problems as for P11.

---

Let me try to clarify what you are tasked to do. The exercise wants you to show that it is impossible to find a subset $P$ of the set of all functions $F$ with the properties P10, P11, P12. (You should ignore that the book might have defined a set $P$ of numbers earlier, there just aren’t enough letters in the alphabet to use a new one every time.)

Where previously, the properties talked about numbers, you now need to translate them to use functions. You did this correctly, except that you shouldn’t have the clause “where $P$ is the collections of all functions $f$ such that $f(x) > 0~\forall x$” in there, because this would *define* $P$ (albeit not with the required properties). Instead, you need to show that this is impossible, no matter how you choose $P$. For example, it also does not work if choose the set of all functions such that $f(0) > 0$.

This is what the solution from the solution manual does. It assumes that you are given a set $P$ with the three properties P10, P11, P12. Then, it constructs two functions $f$ and $g$ where $f$ is zero everywhere except at $x_0$ and $g$ is zero everywhere except at the point $x_1$ (with $x_0 \neq x_1$). Now, it only uses the properties P10, P11, P12. Because of P10, either $f \in P$ or $-f \in P$ and either $g \in P$ or $-g \in P$. (For both functions, we know that the case (i) in P10 is not the case, so (ii) or (iii) must be true if $P$ has the property P10.) Let’s first consider the case that $f, g \in P$. The product function $f g$ is zero everywhere, so it can’t be in $P$ by P10. But by property P12 it needs to in $P$; so we have a contradiction. The other cases that $-f, g \in P$, $f, -g \in P$ or $-f, -g \in P$ are similar. The solution in the manual shortens this to $(\pm f)(\pm g) = 0$.

Comment: You said I shouldn't define $P$ as the collection of functions $f$ such that $f(x)>0\ \forall x$. So in the solution manual solution, what is $P$ after all? For example, $f \in P$ or $-f \in P$. What is $P$?

Comment: The point is that there is not definition of $P$ that will work (in the sense of having properties P10, P11 and P12). To prove an impossibility like this, you assume that you are given a $P$ with these properties and show that you get a contradiction, using *only these properties of $P$*.

Comment: We can conclude that $f \in P$ or $-f \in P$ (if $f \neq 0$) because that is one of the properties that we said $P$ should have (namely, P10).

Comment: I understand the proof now. If we assume that $P10$ holds, then we can show that we can find two functions that (assuming as we did that P10 holds for them) violate $P12$. Therefore, it is impossible for $P10$, $P11$, and $P12$ to hold simultaneously. The thing I still can't quite wrap my head around is the assumption that $P10$ is true. For $P10$ to be true, we need to actually specify what $P$ is a little better. For example, $P$ must at a minimum not contain the constant zero function.

Comment: But that is not enough of a specification to consider $P10$ in isolation. When we consider real numbers, $P$ is a set that really splits the real numbers into $\{0\}$, P, and -P, three disjoint sets, and not just any disjoint sets. This specific split of the real numbers makes it such that by construction only one of the three items in P10 can be true for a number. For functions, we'd need to find a similar split of the set of all functions with real domain, no?

Comment: One more note regarding the proof: it shows that $P10$ is not compatible with $P12$, but can we really say anything useful about whether $P11$ holds or not? Of course we can lump $P11$ in and it becomes equivalent to say $P10$ and $P12$ cannot hold and $P10$, $P11$, and $P12$ cannot hold. But actually it looks to me like we can't say if $P11$ holds or not without knowing what $P$ is.

Comment: Again, our aim is to show that no such split with P10, P11 and P12 can exist. To do this, we *do not* need to show that a $P$ satisfying P10 alone can exist because we never claim that it does. In fact, you can construct a $P$ satisfying P10 but all that I can think of are a bit tricky.

Comment: P10, P11 and P12 are not properties that hold or don’t hold in general. They are properties that a specific set $P$ might or might not have. The proof shows that there is no set $P$ that has the two properties P10 and P12 at the same time, so there certainly is no set that has those two and the additional property P11.